# Guest:admin in multiauth redirects to user login form instead of admin login form in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.4

I am trying to make an admin login on my website. I followed the tutorial so far but the problem is when is use middleware guest:admin like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:admin', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

and type **localhost/website/admin** then it opens the page of **localhost/website/login**

and if i remove admin from guest:admin then it doesn't login and redirect me to **localhost/website/login again** instead of going to admin login page.

I have overrided the showLoginForm() function and guard funtion too. My LoginController looks like this.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/pages/addstudent';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Show the application's login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.index');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('admin');
    }
}
```

I have done too much brain storming on it. Please help!!. It will be much appreciated.

Comment: What does your middleware look like?

Comment: do you mean RedirectIfAuthenticated.php file??

Comment: The `guest` middleware is typically used to prevent an authenticated user from accessing unauthenticated pages. E.g. if a user is already logged in, you don't want them accessing the register page. Is that what you're trying to achieve? Because your question suggests that you should be using the `auth` middleware instead.

Comment: The thing is that i am trying to access my admin login page by typing the url as localhost/website/admin. but due to using guest:admin in constructor of LoginController, it takes me to localhost/website/login page which is my user login page. and if i remove admin from guest:admin then it doesnt login me. i watched this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uE2uS0ZmTPk&index=6&list=PLe30vg_FG4OTO7KbQ6TByyY99AiSw1MDS

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't answer the question. That says what's it's doing, not what you `want` it to do.

Comment: i want to access my admin login page but i can open it. and Thank you for helping me.. i am real frustated by this error.

Comment: So you have an unauthenticated user, who when they try to access a restricted admin page, you'd like to redirect to the admin login page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147582/discussion-between-nagesh-katna-and-fubar).